# Is there a way to enable Executor / Schedule run for user-managed notes on JupyterLab | GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, jupyter-lab

I wish to schedule the trigger/execution of user managed jupyterlab notebooks on the GCP environment at specific intervals *(Hourly/Daily/Weekly etc)*.

I understand that the managed notebooks have an 'Executor' and 'Parameters' option to create a scheduling job.

But is there a workaround for scheduling the user managed notebooks as I am unable to find documentation around that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I came across this package [Jupyter Scheduler](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter-scheduler/) to overcome the problem of scheduling user-managed notebooks on JupyterLab.

Ref: https://blog.jupyter.org/introducing-jupyter-scheduler-f9e82676c388

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is no documented function for scheduled execution in user-managed notebooks and you are correct in availability of this function in [managed notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/schedule-managed-notebooks-run-quickstart#schedule_an_execution).

> 1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Managed notebooks page.
> 2. Next to the managed notebooks instance that you want to use, click Open JupyterLab.
>
>    Your managed notebooks instance opens JupyterLab.
> 3. In the folder File Browser, double-click the example notebook file to open it.
> 4. Click the  Executor button.
> 5. In the Submit notebooks to Executor dialog, enter a name for your bucket in the Cloud Storage bucket field, and then click Create and
>    select. The executor stores your notebook output in the Cloud Storage
>    bucket.
> 6. In the Type field, select Schedule-based recurring executions.
> 7. By default, the executor runs your notebook file every hour at the 00 minute of the hour.
>
> Click Submit.

Your notebook file runs automatically on the schedule that you set.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570002/19378826) is the possibly the closest workaround I have encountered when running scheduled executions and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334756/19378826) referenced using Google's [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer), GCP's take on cloud orchestration.